# Error during installing bpl package to delphi 10.3 @uxtheme@bufferedpaintsetalpha$qqruip11types@Trectuc

Tags: delphi

I have faced the following error "@uxtheme@bufferedpaintsetalpha$qqruip11types@Trectuc" during adding an .bpl library. knowing that my application does not have any theme related code. The code has been written using code Gear Delhi 2007; but i'm trying to use embarcadero delphi 10.3. any workaround?

Comment: Is the BPL compiled with Delphi 2007 or with Delphi 10.3?

Comment: compiled with Delphi 7

Comment: You cannot install a D7 BPL in D10.3, you need to recompile it.

Comment: I don't have the bpl source code. It was an old project and i'm trying to create modern developing environment for it. It has many bpl packages to be installed. Any work around?

Comment: But what is the relation between uxtheme and recompiling the package?

Comment: No, there is no workaround. Without the source or a new BPL you won't be able to use it. It must be compiled with the same compiler version as the application using it. Your Delphi app is trying to **find** the given entry in the export table of the BPL (BPLs are DLLs, but with a lot of version-specific meta-information) and obviously can't find it, hence the error message.

Comment: "relation between uxtheme and recompiling the package"  There isn't one.  Presumably, uxtheme is some kind of component in your BPL.  But you can't use it with any other version of Delphi without recompiling it, and without its source, you can't do that.  There isn't a work-around to this.

Comment: If you don't have the source code to recompile it, you can't use it. Period. Packages are not compatible across versions. And modern versions of Delphi use Unicode strings and have other changes that are not compatible with Delphi 7. This is exactly the reason that you never use Delphi components for which you don't have source.